# Sorting CoreData NSFetchResult by Array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a CoreData dataset like:

```
A | B
-----
1 | c
2 | a
3 | b
```

I would like to sort it using an Array like ["a", "c", "b"] in order to get:

```
A | B
-----
2 | a
1 | c
3 | b
```

Is there a built-in Swift/Foundation/CoreData function to accomplish this?

Comment: Add the code/model that you're using for core data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provide the definition of your Core Data model, I'll give the solution assuming a type containing data like in the question.

Let's assume the type is defined like so,

```
struct Root {
    let id: Int
    let name: String

    init(_ id: Int, _ name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Ofcourse, you'll be using your Core Data model instead of `struct Root`.

Now, the `array` of `results` goes like,

```
let results = [Root(1, "c"), Root(2, "a"), Root(3, "b")]
```

And the `reference` `array` based on which `results` must be sorted,

```
let reference = ["a", "c", "b"]
```

Use **`sorted(_:)`** and **`firstIndex(_:)`** to sort `results` based on `reference`, i.e.

```
let sortedResults = results.sorted {
    if let index1 = reference.firstIndex(of: $0.name), let index2 = reference.firstIndex(of: $1.name) {
        return index1 < index2
    }
    return false
}
print(sortedResults) //[Root(id: 2, name: "a"), Root(id: 1, name: "c"), Root(id: 3, name: "b")]
```